# Which Azure AD version works (should be installed) in a Linux based Azure Deployment Script using PowerShell 6.3

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-deployment

I created an **Azure Deployment Script** that uses **PowerShell 6.3**. Azure automatically creates a **Linux instance** for the script resource. In the **PowerShell script** I'm trying to call the last 3 lines below. **Out-of-the-box** the "Connect-AzureAD" line fails saying "not recognized as a cmdlet". If I install AzureAD.Standard.Preview the Connect-AzureAD line works but the next line "Get-AzureADServicePrincipal" fails saying "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client'. So yeah I bailed on the AzureAD.Standard.Preview. Microsoft documentation says I can use AzureAD with Deployment Scripts. **My question is what version of AzureAD tooling/library/sdk do I install to work with "Azure Deployment Scripts"?** I can only install from PowerShell or Az CLI.

Thanks

```
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"

Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

$miIdentity = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "sqlservername.database.windows.net"
$group = Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id "xxx"
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ID -RefObjectId $miIdentity.ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment in the Cloud shell with some modifications to your script.

I used AzureAD module with version 2.0.2.140

I made the below modifications :

You are using :

```
$miIdentity = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "sqlservername.database.windows.net"
```

Instead, you should use

```
$miIdentity = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "sqlservername"
```

Because, Service Principal only takes the display name instead of full domain name

[image]

You are using :

```
$group = Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id "xxx"
```

Instead, you can use :

```
$group = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString "groupName"
```

After modifications, your code will be similar to below code :

```
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"`
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
$miIdentity = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "sqlservername"
$group = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString "groupName"
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.Id -RefObjectId $miIdentity.ObjectId
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that may help but the root question is for an Azure Deployment Script that uses PowerShell 6.3 or Az CLI how do I install AzureAD from PowerShell and what version of AzureAD for Linux use. I tried the AzureAD.Standard.preview. Is there another/better AzureAD I should use? Thanks again.

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the following errors. I verified the group and identity values are correct. PS /home/james_pierce> Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ID -RefObjectId $miIdentity.ObjectId
Add-AzureADGroupMember: Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: xxxx
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 01 Oct 2021 16:02:12 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

Comment: As per the error, you do not have permissions to add members to the Azure AD Group